# Sunspot/Solr: word concatenation

Tags: solr, full-text-search, sunspot

I'm using Solr with the Sunspot Ruby gem. It works great, but I'm noticing that sometimes users will get poor search results because they have concatenated their search terms (e.g. 'foolproof') where the document text was 'fool proof'. Or vice-versa.

I was going to try and address this by creating a set of alternate match fields by manually concatenating the words from the source documents together. This seems kind of hackish, and implementing the other side (breaking up user concatenations into words) is not obvious.

Is there a way to do this properly in Solr/Sunspot?

Answer (score 1):

Did yo have a look at SOLR spellcheck (or spell check) component?
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent
For example, there is a WordBreakSolrSpellChecker, which may provide valid suggestions in such case.

Comment: Looks like what I need, but we haven't moved to 4.x yet. Is it stable?

Comment: I think it's stable, give it a try